# How can I detect if the first word in a substring is completely in upper case?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a Regex that will return these results in a google sheet. Both the words upper and case are in the same cell including the comma. I am also looking for a way to accomplish this in Google apps script as well, but it isn't a necessity.

```
"UPPER, Case"        =TRUE
"Upper, CASE"        =FALSE
"uPPER, case"        =FALSE
"UppEr, caSe"        =FALSE
"UPPER, case"        =TRUE
"uPPer, case"        =FALSE
```

As you can see, it only returns true if the ***entire first word*** is in upper case.

It should also ignore the comma and the second word.

So I tried this:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z]*\W?

^[A-Z] = check first letter to make sure it is a capital letter
[A-Z]* = any amount of the following letters should be capitalized
\W? = ignore anything following and including the first special character (right?)
```

Please tell me if I am doing this wrong! I am not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match regex should look something like this.

```
^[A-Z]+,\s\w*$
```

Comment: This pretty much nails it, however, it does not work when there is a space before the comma (in my sheet, sometimes, there is), but thank you this works great!

Comment: In that case use this: `^[A-Z]+\s?,\s?\w*$`

Comment: you nailed it man! thanks for your time and attention to detail!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex:

```
[A-Z]+[,\s|\s,][[A-Z].{1}|[a-z].{1}[a-z]+
```

---

**Explanation:**
`[A-Z]+` - indeed catch all the capital letters. **BUT** you want to ensure 2 things. First, that there is a word, this why you should use `+`
`,\s`  - I added this part for your pattern - it has a straight foreword meaning ( a space and comma

Comment: This did not work for me. This returns true regardless of capitalization. I am wondering if Google Sheets does not check explicitly for capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this `([A-Z]{1}[A-Z]+)`

This code verify if the first letter is uppercase and after verify the rest

You can test your regex code in this site http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex

Comment: or ([A-Z][A-Z]+)

Comment: You only need `[A-Z]+` everything else is redundant.

Comment: but if just put [A-Z]+ it will take any uppercase letter

Comment: That's the point. `[A-Z]+` matches one or more of the capital A-Z character class. Your re pattern requires at least two capital letters while mine only requires one... You could also have written yours as `[A-Z]{2,}`

Comment: "UPPER, Case"        =TRUE
"Upper, CASE"        =FALSE
"uPPER, case"        =FALSE
"UppEr, caSe"        =FALSE
"UPPER, case"        =TRUE
"uPPer, case"        =FALSE

Comment: if you put [A-Z]+ everything is true

Comment: I think the best solution is verify how many letter have the word and after verify if is uppercase

Comment: like 'if(var.lenght>1){